# Why can I still not access any DB function in PSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, privileges, sql-grant

This is my `init.sql` file :

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS my_data;
CREATE DATABASE my_data;

DROP USER IF EXISTS u;
CREATE USER u WITH PASSWORD 'secret';

GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO u;
GRANT ALL ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO u;
GRANT ALL ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public TO u;

\c my_data;

CREATE TABLE users (
  ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  password VARCHAR NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  active SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  modified TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  salt VARCHAR NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
);
```

Then if I :

```
psql -f init.sql
```

And..

```
psql -d my_data -U u

my_data=> select * from users;

ERROR:  permission denied for relation users
```

Why would this permission be denied if I just granted it?

**More info**

```
my_data=> \z users
                       Access privileges
 Schema | Name  | Type  | Access privileges | Column access privileges 
--------+-------+-------+-------------------+--------------------------
 public | users | table |                   | 
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only gave permission on the schema, which is separate from the tables. If you want to give permissions on the tables also you can use

```
GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO u;
```

Note that if you have sequences or other objects they also need separate permissions.

This has to be set *after* the tables have been created since permissions are set for existing objects.

If you want to set default permissions for new objects you can use

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO u;
```

Comment: Hmm.. updated my post in relation to your answer to add all grants, but still same error.

Comment: What does `\z users` tell you? Also at what point are you creating the table since it's not shown on the script.

Comment: Updated with the `/z users` response and my create table data in OP

Comment: @Trip You have to grant permissions after creating the table. They're set on existing objects, not new ones

Comment: @Trip Added also how to set defaults that will be set for new tables